# Storing Data in firebase using VBA

Tags: firebase, ms-access, vba, firebase-storage

Is there any way to upload files using VBA to firebase?

> Web code for uploading files in firebase

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage.ref("folderName/file.jpg");
var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
fileUpload.on(‘change’, function(evt) {
  var firstFile = evt.target.file[0]; // get the first file uploaded
  var uploadTask = storageRef.put(firstFile);
  uploadTask.on(‘state_changed’, function progress(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.totalBytesTransferred); // progress of upload
  });
});
```

But how do I use this in VBA? any help is appreciated. Also if you can point to me in right direction.

Comment: This sounds like a bit of a make work project. Why would you want to use Firebase as a backup for MS-Access? Are you going to build the code to recover the database from firebase too? Why not just use a backup MS-Access database - either do a straight copy of the accdb file on a regular scheduled task - or copy data tables via automation?

Comment: Or failing the very valid suggestions @dbmitch has advanced, just copy the database into a zip file named for the current date.

Comment: The question is about, how to store data in firebase using VBA. I would appreciate if the answers are related to this.

Comment: @JohnBingham and dbmitch, Web based backup is better than local backup. As when the Hard disk crashes, we can restore data from cloud.

Comment: @Gustav I am looking for code to upload files to Firebase and download from firebase using VBA

Comment: @dbmitch Thanks :) Since I now know what is possible and what is now. Will implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some [research on Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/). Currently you cannot use VBA to upload files directly to FB Storage, through API.

You can try using JS, as mentioned by you.

Another alternative will be Google Cloud Storage. Which is the back-end for firebase storage.

Answer (score 1):

two ways of doing this.. Assuming there is a website where you can upload files, in such case you can use the standard IE object to navigate to a specific website, find the controls, select the files and using submit or click function upload the file..

The other way is to write a web-service and call it from vba. Both suggestions involves in calling the website/service.

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Navigate "Your upload page.."

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy = True
    DoEvents
Loop
```

we don't have enough information so I just continue with the logic.

- Find the upload document/filename field. insert your filename

  - IE.Document.getElementById("txt_upload_field").Value = myFileName
- find the button/element to upload and perform click/submit action.
- wait for your website and read the result

or you can write your own web service and perform a web-request using XMLHTTP. I personally would go for web-service.

there is also a third way. FTPing to your server..!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking specific to Firebase. Firebase is a google platform.

Comment: Firebase does support apis, check if they provide api for uploading files, if not you have to automate using the IE method. It is equivalent to as if a person would upload the files. There is no such thing as "specific to Firebase from vba" except you have activex component

Comment: Firebase does not have API for VBA. API is only available for JS, Android, iOS

Comment: The whole purpose of Web apis are that you can call it from any platform. Please familiarise yourself with apis.